# Align button with formgroups (bootstrap 3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I vertically align a button to the text box controls?

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Stuff 1</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Stuff 2</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Stuff 3</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2nn422ax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a css solution in jsfiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/2nn422ax/1/

CSS:

```
.row{
  position: relative;
 }

.button-container{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.form-group{
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the button is aligned to the text email above the form field, as it should be. If you use margin:top for the button about maybe 30px, it should align with the text fields if you are talking about the search button. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use modern and agile flexbox:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/2nn422ax/2/)